# Facebook Graph API returns 0 for Post ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-access-token

I am trying to understand if my desktop app is being rate limited... 
My app posts links to a group. I am not getting an error response when I do the post, but I am getting a post ID of 0 returned. Here is what I am seeing:

```
2013.01.10 13:31.13 UTC [D] URL :  "https://graph.facebook.com/493177717399935/feed" 
2013.01.10 13:31.13 UTC [D] ARGS:  "message=Colosseum Missouri Tigers Rival Sleeveless TeeNow: $6.00 80%Sizes: M&link=http://www.kohls.com/kohlsStore/PRD~1012006/testing.jsp&picture=http://media.kohls.com.edgesuite.net/is/image/kohls/1012006&name=Colosseum Missouri Tigers Rival Sleeveless Tee&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN" 
2013.01.10 13:31.14 UTC [D] Recv'd:  "{"id":"493177717399935_0"}"
```

The group ID is correct, but the post ID is 0. The post is not being posted to the group. When this occurs my account is also blocked from posting pictures via the website.

What is causing this and how can I avoid it? I am not seeing an throttling on the Facebook Developer Insights page.

Comment: Does the user context have permission to post? Try switching to a "friends" account.

Comment: Is the user actually in the group?

Comment: Yes, the 'auth_token' was created with the 'publish_actions' permission and the user is a member of the group.

I should add, this works just fine at first, then stops working. I believe I am hitting a limit and would like to know what the limit is and how I can best avoid it.